# How to write unit tests for csv file upload method in django

Tags: django

I've written a method for csv file upload in django now I'm trying to write unit tests for that method.

can we mock csv file using `from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile`, or should I use something else?

Can someone discuss that what approach(mocking, upload) should I follow for this problem?